# Convert Lambda expression C# 2.0

Tags: c#

How to convert expression

```
v => names.Add(v); // Consider names as List<string> and v as string
```

into c# 2.0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an [anonymous method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx) instead:

```
Action<String> action = delegate (string v) { names.add(v); };
```

That will work if the existing lambda expression is being converted into a delegate. It *won't* work when the existing lambda expression is being converted into an expression tree.

(Do you *really* need to use C# 2 though? Eek. Don't forget that you can use C# 3 or higher but still target .NET 2, if that's the *real* requirement. The benefits in productivity for using C# 3 and higher really make it work upgrading your version of Visual Studio...)

Comment: @csLijo: also remember that .NET 3.5 is just .NET 2.0 SP2 with some additional assemblies. It's as safe as a service pack assuming you don't use the new features, and therefore only as dangerous as the new features that you're using.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific example where the lambda arrow actually just invokes an already existing method with unaltered parameter list, you can also just use the **"method group"**.

So

```
v => names.Add(v)
```

can be substituted with just

```
names.Add    /*  OK in C# 2.0, method group conversion  */
```

But in the general case where the lambda is not just equivalent to an existing named method, use an anonymous method like the other answer suggests:

```
delegate (string v) { names.Add(v); }
```

All of these expressions can be assigned to a delegate type like `Action<string>` the has one `string` parameter (value parameter) and returns `void`.